# Make HTML element inherit transform of another

Tags: javascript, html, css-transforms, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a browser extension that draws content on top of images in third party websites. For simplicity, assume that it draws a red box of size `(img.width/2, img.height/2)` over the center of the image. For example, see this figure.

<kbd>[image: screenshot of webpage with figure having a red box overlaid]</kbd>

I am currently creating a red `<div>` and setting it's `style.width`, `style.height`, `style.left` and `style.top` from values computed from the `<img>`. It seems this approach is brittle, as there always will be another fancy transform/animation that I will need to manually handle. For example, I did not think about rotations or skew such as in the below figure.

<kbd>[image: Same screenshot as above but rotated. Box does not rotate with it.]</kbd>

Is there a way to say my `div` should inherit all transformations of the `<img>`, so whatever the page developer does, my content will move according to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this took a bit but I solved it myself.

The key is a function called `getComputedStyle` which returns the net css transform of an image after all operations are performed. You need to stack the non-css transforms with this correctly. I think you can only scale and translate an image without CSS though so this is simple.

```
// get the CSS transform and it's origin
const cssProps = window.getComputedStyle(image);
const transformOrigin = cssProps["transformOrigin"]
const transform: cssProps["transform"]

// get the HTML scaling and translation
const left = image.offsetLeft;
const top = image.offsetTop;
const width = image.width;
const height = image.height;

// create a new element and set it's color
const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.zIndex = 10; 
elem.style.border = 'solid red 2px';
elem.style.position = 'absolute';

// set the css transform and origin
elem.style.transformOrigin = basePos.transformOrigin;
elem.style.transform = `${basePos["transform"]} translate(${left}px, ${top}px)`;
elem.style.width  = `${width/2}px`;
elem.style.height = `${height/2}px`;
```

The only shortcoming of this approach is that you must wait for the page to finish loading before you can use `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: I would say, this is a very verbose solution, but I also haven't tried to solve it myself. Did you try using a flex or grid directive and overlay it?

That is, you make an overlay and apply no select to it and then apply an absolute div to the whole window. with this object positioned using these directives inside that div.

Comment: I added my own non-javascript solution so you don't have to handle the rotate in the javascript.

Comment: I'm very new to HTML/CSS and I don't understand the concepts you have used. A high-level question I have is how does it know which image on the page I am referring to?

Comment: So basically. Something is rotating on your screen, your problem is you're placing an overlay outside of whatever is rotating so it's not moving. You need to create your overlay inside whatever is rotating. That's what my answer shows you how to do. Otherwise you change nothing on how you place your overlay, just that it goes in the section that allows you to overlay the rotating element.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems kinda over the top to me. Idk if you tried this, but making that div that encompasses the entirety of the rotating window relative and then doing something like this will work also...

**html:**

```
<body> <!-- or whatever the parent is of the whole view -->
  <div class="overlay-window">
    <div class="image-overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**scss:**

```
body {
  position: relative;
  .overlay-window {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute:
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    .image-overlay {
      // add grid styling in the parent of this to position your 
      // image outline or however you want to position it here
    }
  }
}
```

Even just making the overlay would remove the need for that javascript stuff tbh. This should avert the need to rotate and all that as it will actually be apart of the rotating object.